# If Condition failing inside ssh

Tags: ssh, openssh

Hi I tried below code

```
ssh $p_ftp_user@$IP $SPATH
if [$? -eq 0]; then echo "ok" else echo "test" | mailx -r test@gmail.com -s "File Failure" $v_email_id fi
```

i want to check if `$SPATH` in same session if  command is success then ok if not mail has to be sent .
But i tried multiple ways with if but getting error message as "then unmatched" ,
if [$? -eq 0] then echo "ok" , if ; is removed it is saying "if unmatched".
Please let me know how i can resolve this issue.

Comment: `[$? -eq 0]` should be `[ $? -eq 0 ]` and you’ll need a `;` before `fi`.

Comment: ssh $p_ftp_user@$IP $SPATH;"if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo "test" | mailx test.com -s 'File Failure' 'test1@gmail.com'; fi"  i am trying to write if in the same line but getting this below error  "not found" can you let me know where it is going wrong because mail is not being sent.